# Verification of epsilon - delta proof $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ { x }^{ 3 }=8 }$

Tags: real-analysis

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ { x }^{ 3 }=8 } $$

Let ε>0 be given

$\ |x-2||x^2+4+2x|< ε$

$\  ≤1$

$\ 1<x^2<9$

$\ 2<2x<6$ or $\ |2x| <6 $

$\ |x^2|+4+|2x| < 9+6+4$

$\ |x-2|(|x^2|+4+|2x|) < 19$

Since,
$\ |x-2||x^2+4+2x| ≤|x-2|(|x^2|+4+|2x|) $,

$\ |x-2||x^2+4+2x|<19$

So =min(ε/19 , 1)

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: An epsilon delta proof should always start with some variation of "let $\varepsilon>0$ be given". So unless you have that, you have an incomplete proof.

Comment: @ZacharySelk My bad I'll edit that in. Is it logically correct though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it logically correct though?

The calculations are fine but the way you write it, you seem to start with *what you have to show*, namely:

> $$\ |x-2||x^2+4+2x|< ε$$

You could consider your work so far, finding a suitable $\delta$ by starting from what you want to show, as the preparatory (or scratch) work. Now you can write a concise proof.

---

For any $\varepsilon>0$, you take $\delta = \mbox{min}\left\{ 1,\tfrac{\varepsilon}{19}\right\}$. This choice of $\delta$ ensures that for any $x$ satisfying $|x-2|<\delta$, you also have (see your work):

- $|x-2|<\tfrac{\varepsilon}{19}$
- $|x^2+4+2x|<19$

so you have:
$$\left|x-2\right|<\delta \implies \left|x^3-8\right| = \left|x-2\right|\left|x^2+4+2x\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{19}\cdot19=\varepsilon$$

Comment: Thanks @Barry Cipra for correcting the typo.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering why we write δ=min(1,ϵ/(19) instead of just δ=ϵ/19. Is it because for δ<ϵ/19 to be true, δ<1 and if ϵ/19>1 then δ>1 which would make the result that δ<ϵ/19 not valid because δ>1?

Comment: We used $\delta<1$ to get an (easy) upper bound on the other factor ($|x^2+4+2x|<19$). In order for this upper bound to be valid, we need $\delta$ below 1, which isn't necessarily the case for all $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok.

Rephrasing:

Consider $|x-2|<1$, then $1<x<3.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

$|x^3-8|= |x-2||x^2 +2x+4|<$

$ |x-2||9+6+4|= 19|x-2|.$

Choose $\delta < \min(1, \epsilon/(19))$.

Then

$|x-2| <\delta$  implies

$|x^3-8|< 19|x-2|<19\delta < \epsilon.$

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering why we write   δ<min(1,ϵ/(19) instead of   δ<ϵ/19. Is it because for δ<ϵ/19 to be true, δ<1 ?

Comment: Arjun.First we use |x-2|<1 to get 1<x a lower bound to use in the inequality.The we go for |x-2|< delta. If we use min of 1,\epsilon/19 we can use all inequalities.Need to get used.Let 1<epsilon/19, look what happens, then let epsilon/19 <1 go through all inequalities.OK?